# What does 2 values vertically arranged in parenthesis in an equation mean?

Tags: combinations

Below is the particular expression I am concerned with.

[image]

I suppose it denotes some sort of operation but I am unsure as to what. I'd appreciate some guidance. Thanks.

Comment: That notation almost always refers to the [Binomial Coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient)

Comment: Looks like a binomial coefficient.

Comment: It's another symbol for "combinations"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is the Binomial coefficient
$$ \binom w i = \frac{w!}{i!(w-i)!}
$$
Or
$$ \binom w i = \frac{w^{\underline i}}{i!}
$$
where $w^{\underline i} = w(w-1)\dots(w-i+1)$ is the falling factorial.

Answer (score 5):

It's almost always a binomial coefficient:
$$
\binom{n}{k} 
$$
(often pronounced "$n$ choose $k$")
denotes the number of ways to choose $k$ elements from a set of $n$ elements.